# quotes are lost from validation error message with omnifaces `o:validateMultiple`

Tags: jsf-2, omnifaces

I am using Omnifaces 1.7 to validate multiple fields in my JSF 2 form. More precisely, I use the following snippet

```
<o:validateMultiple 
          id="activiteValidator" 
          components="programmeCreation programmeReport dateEcheance"
          validator="#{activiteControleFacesValidator}" 
          message="L'activité n'est pas cohérente." />
```

which works as intended except for one small glitch ; the quotes in the error message are lost when the message is shown because the validation error is triggered. This is what I get in the HTML in case of validation failed

```
Lactivité nest pas cohérente.
```

If you know what is wrong with this configuration or how I could circumvent that problem, I would be most thankful.

Update : if I try to escape the quote, it still doesn't work. When `message="L\'activité"`, the HTML result is `L\activité`.

Comment: Try this: `message="L\'activité n\'est pas cohérente."`.

Comment: Sorry my post wasn't complete enough. I had already tried that and I have updated my post.

Comment: Could you try to put your messages' expressions somewhere else other than the view (in model layer or through bundle functionality) ?

Comment: The problem is identical if the message comes from a bean getter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by the [`MessageFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) API which is under the covers being used for message formatting (substituting `{0}`, `{1}`, etc). The apostrophe (single quote) is actually an escape character.

You need to escape the single quote by another one in order to display it as-is.

```
<o:validateMultiple 
    ...
    message="L''activité n''est pas cohérente." />
```

An alternative is to use a curly right single quote.

```
<o:validateMultiple 
    ...
    message="L’activité n’est pas cohérente." />
```